# Dialoag method won't open in XP

Tags: python, tkinter, dialog, windows-xp

I had a similar forum post up. But considering it was wrong, and probably pointless I am going to try recreate a more accurate a post.

**Issue:**

`tkFileDialog.askdirectory()` is not working on my boss's computer. It is a Windows XP 32 bit OS. The build is python 2.7.10 and compiled into py2exe.

Now I have had this application tested on a windows xp machine with a similar set up to his. and it works fine. He was on Python 2.7.8 and we upgraded to the newer version.  We have also tried running the script as is from the machine. **None of this works.**

**Workaround:**

We have been able to do a workaround using `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()` which works perfectly fine. So we know it's not the `tkFileDialog` class but the `askdirectory()` method call instead.  I have since modified the code to make this "acceptable".

**Requirement/Request:**

Does anyone know what would be the issue with the `askdirectory` method? We need this method to call "all files in a directory" for "function-reiterated"? At the moment it just calls "a file" for "function".

Comment: "I had a similar form up. " - what does that mean? similar to what?

Comment: Similar post. I'll correct it now